# Sending an HTML email, from php document

Tags: php, html-email

So I am in the process of gathering a user's email address and submitting it to a database - but what I would really like to do is also submit an HTML email to them.

I have created the html of the email (with inline css, it is literally 1 page) and it looks like this:
[image]

So then I took this code and wrote the email submittingness in php:

```
ini_set("sendmail_from", "emailer@benjaminpotter.org");

    $to = $email;
    $subject = "Ben Potter Web Design - Newsletter Form Submission";   

    $emailthing = '    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Form Submission - Newsletter Update</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color:#e8faff;   
}

p {
    font-size:15px;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color:#141414;
    font-style:italic;
}

#mainbox{
    background-image:url(http://www.benjaminpotter.org/Images/emailtotheuser.jpg);
    width:345px;
    height:404px;   
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:block;
    margin-top:50px;
}

#mainbox #textholder{
    width:279px;
    height:300px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:80px;
    margin-left:30px;   
}

#special{
    color:#72C0EF;
    text-align:center !important;
    font-style:normal;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="mainbox">
<div id="textholder">
<p>
Thanks for signing up!<br />
I currently have you under the email:<br />
<span id="special">' . $email . '</span>
<br />
<br />
You will be receiving tri-monthly / <br />
quarterly emails from me, updating you<br />
on my latest works.<br />
<br />
Thank you for your intrest in <strong>Ben Potter
Web Design</strong>, you will receive the first newsletter soon.<br />
<br />
<br />
Yours Sincerely,
<br />
<strong>Ben Potter</strong>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>';  

$Rconfucious = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";   
$Rconfucious .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";        
$Rconfucious .= 'From: Ben Potter Web Design 2011 <emailer@benjaminpotter.org>' . "\r\n";

@mail($to, $subject, $emailthing, $Rconfucious);
```

But the problem is that it comes through like this:

[image]

So how do I get this to work properly?
Also, just a side note - the emails always go straight to junk mail and I don't know how to change this... the user won't see the email if it goes straight there.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your email is correctly being sent as HTML. However, CSS/HTML support in email clients is akin to the situation we had in 1998.

Gmail for example doesn't support `<style>` tags which is why your email is rendering the way it is. I suggest you take a look at [the following chart](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) in order to see what each email client supports and to tailor your HTML template accordingly.

So, essentially, your email has to be written as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Form Submission - Newsletter Update</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#72c0ef">
<div style="background-image:url(http://www.benjaminpotter.org/Images/emailtotheuser.jpg); width:345px; height:404px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; display:block; margin-top:50px;">
<div style="width:279px; height:300px; display:block; position:absolute; margin-top:80px; margin-left:30px;">
<p style="font-size:15px; font-family:Georgia, \'Times New Roman\', Times, serif; color:#141414; font-style:italic;">
Thanks for signing up!<br />
I currently have you under the email:<br />
<span class="color:#72C0EF; text-align:center !important; font-style:normal;">' . $email . '</span>
<br />
<br />
You will be receiving tri-monthly / <br />
quarterly emails from me, updating you<br />
on my latest works.<br />
<br />
Thank you for your intrest in <strong>Ben Potter
Web Design</strong>, you will receive the first newsletter soon.<br />
<br />
<br />
Yours Sincerely,
<br />
<strong>Ben Potter</strong>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an email library. SwiftMailer has been around for awhile and it's very well featured and robust.

The documentation for creating html messages is here: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html

For example, this creates an email message that supports both HTML and plain text for legacy clients:

```
//Pass it as a parameter when you create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject here', 'My amazing body');

//Or set it after like this
$message->setBody('My <em>amazing</em> body', 'text/html');

//Add alternative parts with addPart()
$message->addPart('My amazing body in plain text', 'text/plain');
```

Regarding emails going to spam, I would recommend reading [So You'd Like To Send Some Email (Through Code)](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html). The key is to either configure your server correctly for sending email or use a third party provider like [postmarkapp](http://postmarkapp.com/) or [sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com)

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE:**

The above was meant as a suggestion to improve email handling in your code. Perhaps it didn't address the fact that Gmail doesn't support  tags, but I stand by recommending the use of an email library.

Comment: -1: This has nothing to do with the situation above. The email is correctly being sent as HTML. The problem is that Gmail doesn't support `<style>` tags.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Andrew. I realize the answer didn't address the <style> issue that you pointed out, but I still think it was worth mentioning the existence of advanced email libraries in addition to addressing his issue with spam.

Answer (score 0):

HTML in emails is send as another file. You should pass plain text email (for those who dont use fancy mail clients with html viewer) and need an additional file with mime type text/html using base64 and some email building rules. To see how it looks (in gmail) open any html message and then find see orginal function (in "v" menu next to reply button above message).

In simplest case (without plaintext) you could try this:
mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: $from\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");

For attaching also plaintext for some readers convenience or attaching files (and images) look there:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#105661 ("Send Multi attachment email" comment).

There's an example of combining both plaintext and html:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#83491  (comment with "28-May-2008 01:55" date)